# Mule Maven tests throw ClassNotFoundException all of a sudden

Tags: mule

All of a sudden all my Mule Maven projects are throwing this error when running mvn clean test:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException
    at org.mule.tck.junit4.AbstractMuleTestCase.(AbstractMuleTestCase.java:71)

I can add a dependency for it, but I shoudln't really have to.

Nothings changed in my code. I am using Mule 3.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `commons-cli.jar` in your classpath, add this Maven dependency to your pom

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Update: OP's code was fixed after adding `commons-cli 1.1` dependency.

Comment: It's the commons-cli dependency that is the issue. Mule 3.4 is bringing in v 1.2 which doesnt have the ParseException class the test dependency relies on.

Comment: Try adding this above dependency.. this will bring common-cli classes. See my version number update

Comment: Thanks, I don't mind adding it. But should Mule take care of this? It used to work before without adding it.

Comment: Even adding v 1.2 specifically doesn't fix it. Only adding 1.1 fixes it.

Comment: Yes adding 1.1 fixes the error. But I still think Mule should take car of it's own transitive dependencies.

Comment: Agree.. you can file a bug report in Jira. Wondering what error was it throwing after adding 1.2 dependency

Comment: Thanks, it was the same exception - ClassNotFoundException

Answer (score 2):

Issue description and how to fix it: http://ricston.com/blog/mule-classnotfoundexception-tests-commons-cli/

In a nutshell, you probably have an incorrect JAR named commons-cli-1.2. Delete that and rerun your maven build. You should be good after that.

Answer (score 0):

If the follogin dependency in available in the POM. it should be working fine.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
        <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Then use mvn clean compile to update the dependency.

```
mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse clean compile
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.mule.tests</groupId>
   <artifactId>mule-tests-functional</artifactId>
   <version>${mule.version}</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency> where the mule.version is 3.4.0 but it doesnt have the transitive dependency for commons-cli

Comment: Are you using Eclipse IDE? If so did you try     mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse clean compile

Comment: I will try that, but I noticed that 3.4 brings in commons-cli v 1.2 which doesnt have that class anymore. Whereas v 1.1 does. This seems like a bug with Mule dependency versions?

Comment: I could see the class ParseException available in the commons-cli v 1.2        http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.2/org/apache/commons/cli/ParseException.java

Comment: When I look at the jar though in referenced libraries, It's not there, just a bunch of groovy packages.

Answer (score 0):

Maven behaviour isn't reproducible from one run to the next: apart from generic network problems and repository corruption problems, anything might be updated automatically at any time, breaking any step of the execution, even if you don't change any of your files.

Your error message about a class in some Apache Commons library suggests a disagreement between the version of that library Mule should be using (one that has the ParseException class) and the library version it actually loads (without the class and causing the exception).

Plausible version mismatch scenarios include an update to a buggy new version of Mule (maybe only to a wrong or corrupted POM) which specifies an incompatible library version, or a random upgrade or downgrade of the latest library version in your repository as a consequence of adding or updating something unrelated to Mule.

Analysis suggestions:

- What plugins in your Maven repository have a snapshot version? Which ones of these snapshots were updated around the time the error first appeared?
- Which library jars, and which versions, include the ParseException class? What depends on specific versions or on the latest version of those jars?